# NEST 2.0 with Elasticsearch for GeoDistance always returns all records

Tags: elasticsearch, nest, geo

I have the below code using C# .NET 4.5 and NEST 2.0 via nuget.  This query always returns my type 'trackpointes' with the total number of documents with this distance search code. I have 2,790 documents and the count return is just that.  Even for 1 centimeter as the distance unit it returns all 2,790 documents.  My type of 'trackpointes' has a location field, type of geo_point, geohash true, and geohash_precision of 9.

I am just trying to filter results based on distance without any other search terms and for my 2,790 records it returns them all regardless of the unit of measurement. So I have to be missing something (hopefully small). Any help is appreciated. The NEST examples I can find are a year or two old and that syntax does not seem to work any more.

```
double distance = 4.0;
var geoResult = client.Search<TrackPointES>(s => s.From(0).Size(10000).Type("trackpointes")
    .Query(query => query
    .Bool( b => b.Filter(filter => filter
                .GeoDistance(geo => geo
                .Distance(distance, Nest.DistanceUnit.Kilometers).Location(35, -82)))
             )
           )
       );
```

If I use POSTMAN to connect to my instance of ES and POST a search w/ the below JSON, I get a return of 143 total documents out of 2,790. So I know the data is right as that is a realistic return.

```
{
"query" : {
    "filtered" : {
        "filter" : {
            "geo_distance" : {
                "distance" : "4km",
                "location" : {
                    "top_left": {
                        "lat" : 35,
                        "lon" : -82
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: You may want to consider using scan and scroll to get 10,000 results back (maybe 500 at a time) as opposed to asking Elasticsearch to return them all to you in one request; it may put less stress on your cluster - https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-request-scroll.html

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Looks like you didn't specify field in your query. Try this one:

```
var geoResult = client.Search<Document>(s => s.From(0).Size(10000)
    .Query(query => query
        .Bool(b => b.Filter(filter => filter
            .GeoDistance(geo => geo
                .Field(f => f.Location) //<- this 
                .Distance(distance, Nest.DistanceUnit.Kilometers).Location(35, -82)))
        )
    )
    );
```

Comment: that was totally it and I appreciate the response @Rob. I cannot +1 yet but I would if I could.

Answer (score 1):

I forgot to specify the field to search for the location. :( But I am posting here just in case someone else has the same issue and to shame myself into trying harder...

**.Field(p => p.location)** was the difference in the query.

```
        var geoResult = client.Search<TrackPointES>(s => s.From(0).Size(10000).Type("trackpointes")
          .Query(query => query
           .Bool( b => b.Filter(filter => filter
                .GeoDistance(geo => geo.Field(p => p.location).DistanceType(Nest.GeoDistanceType.SloppyArc)
                .Distance(distance, Nest.DistanceUnit.Kilometers).Location(35, -82)))
             )
           )
       );
```

Comment: Not gonna lie. I have just done the exact same thing; thank you for this question and answer 